# External functions inside filter of dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How does an external function inside dplyr::filter know the columns just by their names without the use of the data.frame from which it is coming?

For example consider the following code:

```
filter(hflights, Cancelled == 1, !is.na(DepDelay))
```

How does is.na know that DepDelay is from hflights? There could possibly have been a DepDelay vector defined elsewhere in my code. (Assuming that hflights has columns named 'Cancelled', 'DepDelay').

In python we would have to use the column name along with the name of the dataframe. Therefore here I was expecting something like

```
!is.na(hflights$DepDelay)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not an expert enough to give a precise answer, hopefully I won't lead you too far astray.

It is essentially a question of environment. `filter()` first looks for any vector object within the data frame environment named in its first argument. If it doesn't find it, it will then go "up a level", so to speak, to the global environment and look for any other vector object of that name. Consider:

```
library(dplyr)

Species <- iris$Species
iris2 <- select(iris, -Species) # Remove the Species variable from the data frame.

filter(iris2, Species == "setosa")
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#> 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#> 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

More information on the topic can be found [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html) (warning, the book is a work in progress).

Most functions from the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages are specifically designed to handle data frames, and all of those functions require the name of the data frame as their first argument. This allows for usage of the pipe (`%>%`) which allows to build a more intuitive workflow. Think of the pipe as the equivalent of saying "... and then ...". In the context shown above, you could do:

```
iris %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa")
```

And you get the same output as above. Combining the concept of the pipe and focusing the lexical scope of variables to the referenced data frames is meant to lead to more readable code for humans, which is one of the principles of the tidyverse set of packages, which both `dplyr` and `tidyr` are components of.